# Emacs indentation of break after switch statement

Tags: c, emacs, elisp, indentation

Right now the standard emacs indentation works like the following:

```
switch (cond) {
case 0: {
  command;
}
  break;
}
```

I want the break; to line up with case.

Also, is there a list of the c-set-offset commands somewhere?

Comment: You know that the brackets between the case and break are unnecessary unless you need to 1) declare variables in the case and 2) branch into the case, don't you?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The biggest help (I've found) in customizing indentation is figuring out what cc-mode uses to indent the current line.  That's what <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd> aka <kbd>M-x c-set-offset</kbd> can do - it'll allow you to customize the offset for a syntactic element, and it shows you what element was used for the current line!

Here's how you can customize it.  Move your cursor to the `break;` line.

```
C-c C-o RET 0 RET
```

At which point, your code will be indented like:

```
switch (cond) {
case 0: {
  command;
}
break;
}
```

For documentation on the offsets, check out the docstring for the variable `'c-offsets-alist`

```
C-h v c-offsets-alist RET
```

Similarly, you can add this to your .emacs:

```
(setq c-offsets-alist '((statement-case-intro . 0)))
```

The documentation for customizing indention is [here](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Customizing-Indentation.html#Customizing-Indentation) and is worth reading.  There are tons of ways to do it, so reading the manual is worth the time (if you want non-default indentation).  And here's a pointer to all the [syntactic symbols](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Syntactic-Symbols.html#Syntactic-Symbols) used in cc-mode.

Comment: I don't know if this answer was useful for the OP, but it damn sure was for me. I've been annoyed by emacs's insisting on indenting the opening curly-brace on blocks for years. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly. I have been using emacs for a couple of years but only recently started customizing it. So the emacs-lisp is all foreign to me. Thanks for the doc.

Comment: Sadly, `statement-case-intro` affects the first statement in a case, whatever it is. I'd like just to outdent `break`, and I can find no way to do this. (Not my personal preference, I'm just trying to write a style consistent with an existing code base.)

Answer (score 1):

For me, getting php-mode switch statements to indent correctly requires:

```
      (c-set-offset (quote brace-list-entry) 2 nil)
      (c-set-offset (quote case-label) 2 nil)
```

But as others have mentioned, C-c C-o is your friend.....